# How do I bind to a non-native property in Angular 2?

Tags: typescript, angular

I'm trying to bind values to an element attribute that is non-native and obviously the usual approach isn't working:

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, Input, OnInit, HostBinding} from 'angular2/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[myFeet]'
})
export class MyFeetDirective {

    @HostBinding('feet')
    @Input() feetProps:string

    constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }
}
```

I'm referencing this directive like this:

```
<div [myFeet]="body.footCount"></div>
```

And I want this to be the end result in the DOM (i.e. post-Angular rendering):

```
<div feet="2"></div>
```

I have managed to achieve this by simply using an ngOnInit function that sets the attributes like so:

```
ngOnInit(){
    this._setAttributes();
}

private _setAttributes(){
    if (this._feetProps != null) {
        this._el.nativeElement.setAttribute("feet", this._feetProps);
    }
}
```

But this isn't the Angular way and I wondered what is?

p.s.  I think the performance benefits of Angular 2 are in some way linked to the adherence to the native DOM, but is there a way to override this for custom elements/attributes?  Maybe this is wrong, either way, I'd appreciate your insight.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure if my answer is what you are looking for. I have a hard time figuring out from your question what your problem is and how the result of the solution should look like. What do you mean by "obviously the usual approach isn't working:"? If you want `<div myFeet="2"></div>` in the DOM then just write `<div myFeet="2"></div>`

Comment: Thanks, Gunter, It certainly seems like the right idea, but I'm still struggling to get it working.  If I add the 'attr.' prefix then the output doesn't appear.  I'm still fiddling with it, but NG2 is very new to me.  I'll update this with anything I find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the attribute to be added to the DOM use attribute binding syntax instead of property binding syntax.

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[myFeet]'
})
export class MyFeetDirective {

    @HostBinding('attr.feet') 
    @Input() feetProps:string
}
```

Comment: I kind of feel like your answer would have been the perfect solution for clarity if NG2 supported that syntax with the square-brackets (e.g.  @HostBinding('[attr.feet]').  It throws an invalid character error, though.  Cheers, anyway!

Comment: `[]` are implicit in `@HostBinding`. Just use `@HostBinding('attr.feet')`

Comment: That's the first thing I tried, but I got no output.  ...You've made me check again and since I've cleaned out my directive (rebuilt using the simple example above) it's working.  I must have had something in there that was conflicting.  Dargh!  Sorry, this answer is correct :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use the value of the directive input to set the attribute using the `host` block of the directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[myFeet]',
  host: {
    '[attr.feet]': 'myFeetValue'
  }
})
export class MyFeetDirective {
  @Input('myFeet')
  myFeetValue:string
}
```

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/KYSIzmAqWLrc2n0yR8j5?p=preview

Comment: Yes! thankyou!  I'd seen this syntax in some examples but they appeared to be the 'old' way and not that seen in the angular docs.  https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html.  Could you point me at the reference for this info at all?  I'd like to use whichever is most up-to-date (understanding that it it a WIP).  Thanks again, much appreciated :)